# Check if element exist in row, but limit only to current row

Tags: jquery

I have a table that looks like this:

```
<table>
 <tr><td><input class="serv1" type="checkbox" name="ser1[]" id="ser1[]" value="Yes"></td><td><input class="serv2" type="checkbox" name="ser2[]" id="ser2[]" value="Yes" ></td><td><input class="serv3" type="checkbox" name="ser3[]" id="ser3[]" value="Yes" ></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input class="serv1" type="checkbox" name="ser1[]" id="ser1[]" value="Yes"></td><td></td><td><input class="serv3" type="checkbox" name="ser3[]" id="ser3[]" value="Yes"></td></tr>
</table>
```

With jquery, when clicking on i.e ser3[] (first row) I check if ser2[] (also in first row) is checked, if not I do not allow if to be checked.

In row 2 I do not have a ser2[] so I have to check if ser2[] exist if not, check if ser1[] is checked (there will always be a ser1[] and ser3[])

my code is as follow: (I only inserted the part of the code I'm having trouble with)

```
$('.serv3').change(function() {
if($(this).parents('tr').find('td.serv2')){
        alert('exist')}
    else{
        alert('Not Exist')
    }

});
```

My problem is that even in row 2 when I check ser3[] it finds a ser2[], and I can only presume that is finding the ser2[] in row 1.
So my question is how can I limit the .find() to the current row only.

Thanks!

Comment: `id` should be unique.

Comment: try .closest('td.serv2') and test with length > 0

Comment: id's are unique, the rows are dynamically generated so that's why I'm using [], I just don't know what the id's will be so cant do a search via id's,

Answer (score 0):

you can do it right that

```
$('.serv3').on('change', function () {
   if($(this).closest('td').siblings('td').find('.serv2').length){
      alert('exist');
   }
   else{
      alert('not exist');
   }
```

});